# How to use apply function to 2 series?

Tags: python

```
s1=[[123,456,789...],[234,567,89],.....]
s2=[[123,...],[567,89],.....]
df=[s1,s2]
```

`s2[i]` is a sub list of `s1[i]`, which means `set(s2[i])<set(s1[i])`

I want to add col `s3` that makes `set(s3[i])=set(s1[i])-set(s2[i])`

Comment: There is no duplicated number in each list

Answer (score 0):

```
s3=[]
for i in range(len(s1)):
    s3.append(list(set(s1[i])-set(s2[i])))
```

or

```
s3=[list(set(s1[i])-set(s2[i]))for i in range(len(s1))]
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.